# R - check if is value or NA in a column and if not copy from column on left

Tags: r

I have problem with R like in a title. I have a data frame with 40+ rows and some kind of data in 2 columns I am interested in. What I want to do is to check if in column 2 is value or NA, and if there is NA copy value from the same row in column 1 (might be empty as well). I don't know exactly what approach should be used in this situation.

Regards,
Rafał

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ifelse` here:

```
df$col2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$col2), df$col1, df$col2)
```

This says, in English terms, to replace `col2` with the value from `col1` should the former be `NA`, otherwise leave the value as it was.